# Why does Windows show my hard disk is 99% full no matter how many things I delete?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning

I have an old laptop running Windows XP. It has an 80GB disk but no matter how many things that I have deleted it still shows 99% is used - it never changes.

I have scanned it with HDTune but found no physical problems and in the folder size section, the real space used is less than 40GB. Right now I can't put anything in it nor can I use any software that needs space.

There is only one hard disk and one partition - `C:`.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Have you emptied the recylce bin?

Comment: +1 for check if recycle bin in empty as that's the only way space gets reduced.

Comment: have you defragmented?

Comment: Try to create another partition with `Partition Wizard` or `Easeus` and let us know what happen.

Comment: You should run chkdsk.

Answer (score 6):

[WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) will be able to give you a clue which directory/file is taking disk space.

You may also want to check how much space you have assigned for System Restore. You can see it by right clicking "My Computer" and then choose "Properties" in the menu.

But by the way, did you forget to empty your recycle bin in Windows?

Comment: for sure i have my recycle bin empty ... i deleted softwares, i deteled files and still no spare space.

Comment: WinDirStat shows only 33g is used in the disk. But windows tells me 99% percent is used, cant put anything in.